# Array subtraction in mysli_fetch_assoc

Tags: php

I have some sorting problem to this i want it to compare properly but the array result is incrementing

```
$query=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM questions WHERE MATCH (question) AGAINST ('$msg*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) limit $limit ");
   }
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $id = $row ["id"];  
    $question = $row ["question"];      

    $answer = $row ["answer"];            


    $words2 = explode(" ", cleanWords($question));
    foreach($words2 as $word) 
      {
        $stem = PorterStemmer::Stem($word);
        if(!in_array($stem, $stop_words)) {
            $stem_words[] = $stem;

        }

    }
    print_r($stem_words);
    echo "<br>";
  }

}
```

Now my result set is incrementing like

```
Array ( [0] => What [1] => IT [2] => STAFF [3] => )
Array ( [0] => What [1] => IT [2] => STAFF [3] => [4] => what [5] => it [6] => )
Array ( [0] => What [1] => CEIT [2] => UCC [3] => [4] => what [5] => it [6] => [7] => Where [8] => it [9] => )
```

**I want to get the result like this

```
Array ( [0] => What [1] => IT [2] => STAFF [3] => )
Array (  [0] => what [1] => it [2] => )
Array ( [0] => Where [1] => it [2] => )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are just adding each word to the `$stem_words` array.  Instead for each record, build a list of words for this record (`$newList` in this code) and add this record to the `$stem_words` array...

```
$newList = [];
foreach($words2 as $word)
{
    $stem = PorterStemmer::Stem($word);
    if(!in_array($stem, $stop_words)) {
        $newList[] = $stem;
    }
}
$stem_words[] = $newList;
```

Comment: Thanks man i was debugging it for almost a week thank you so much :)

Comment: you are the best i was trying so many ways. Thank you so much